# MySQL does not use first column of a composite primary key

Tags: mysql, join, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have one big data table tbl1 with the following keys:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`,`entry_id`,`position`),
KEY `idx_log_id` (`log_id`)
```

column definitions:

```
log_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
entry_id mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
position tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
affiliate_id mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
```

and a smaller table tbl2 with only a key:

```
KEY `ix_log_id` (`log_id`,`affiliate_id`)
```

column definitions:

```
log_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
affiliate_id bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
```

Both tables have the same engine (MyISAM) and charset.

I intend to join them.

```
explain 
select * 
from 
  tbl1, 
  tbl2
where
  tbl1.log_id = tbl2.log_id
  and tbl1.affiliate_id = tbl2.affiliate_id;
```

And it looks ok. tbl2 is scanned (2.5m rows) and each row is joined with tbl1 using the KEY `idx_log_id` With a cardinality of 4. Great.

Now I think: the KEY `idx_log_id` indexes the same column as the first column of my primary key. So it should not be necessary. And indeed, the EXPLAIN shows PRIMARY,idx_log_id as possible keys.

Now I do

```
explain 
select * 
from 
  tbl1 ignore key (idx_log_id), 
  tbl2 
where
  tbl1.log_id = tbl2.log_id
  and tbl1.affiliate_id = tbl2.affiliate_id;
```

and with ignoring the idx_log_id I hope mysql uses the primary key instead.

But no. instead of using keys from tbl1, it does a full table scan of tbl1 which is over 4 billion rows, and joins them against ix_log_id from tbl2 which is far inferior.

I am using mySQL 5.1 and I have not been able to explain why mySQL is unable to use the first column of a composite primary key for a join.
Does anyone have help for me?

Comment: please give us the correct data here, in your spec of tbl1 there's no affiliate_id

Comment: I only included the column definitions of columns part of the pk/index. I now provided the affiliate_id though it's not related to the problem

Comment: Is this a benchmark or why don't you add an index for the affiliate_id on tbl1.

Comment: I don't want to add an additional key on a 4 billion row table for one particular use case. And even if I did, it would not answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the probable issue here:
mySQL did not create proper statistics for the Primary key. The cardinality for the first and the second column of the composite PK was NULL, only the last column had a cardinality (equal to the number of rows in the table). Since the first key column did not have a cardinality, the optimiser could not use this column for joining.

This seems to be a reproducible problem. When I create a composite index on a test table, all columns of the index have a cardinality. For a primary key on the same column, the cardinality is NULL for all columns except for the last one.

An ANALYZE TABLE fixes this problem, but is not feasible for big tables or tables in production.

I am not sure if this is a bug with our particular version, or more in general for mySQL. The version we use:
5.1.73-rel14.11-log
(Percona Server (GPL), 14.11, Revision 603)

key statistics after analyze:

```
 Table  Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Cardinality
 tbl1   0   PRIMARY     1   log_id      840106431
 tbl1   0   PRIMARY     2   entry_id    840106431
 tbl1   0   PRIMARY     3   position    4200532155
 tbl1   1   idx_log_id  1   log_id      840106431
```

before, it looked like this:

key statistics before analyze:

```
 Table  Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Cardinality
 tbl1   0   PRIMARY     1   log_id      <null>
 tbl1   0   PRIMARY     2   entry_id    <null>
 tbl1   0   PRIMARY     3   position    4200532155
 tbl1   1   idx_log_id  1   log_id      840106431
```

Comment: Please post the statistics for the primary key after > analyze table